# Counting keystrokes and clicks in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, click-counting

I'm trying to create an application similar to the site WhatPulse, which will generate an image with my clicks and keystrokes. WhatPulse only updates the image once every 24 hours, so I am going to make an application to keep track of that for me, only with realtime stats.

How can I count total keystrokes (outside of the application itself) as well as total clicks, in vb.net?

This is for personal use.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a premade component to help you.  [Here is one](http://download.cnet.com/Keylogger-DLL/3000-2094_4-10397887.html) that has demos for VB.NET.

Comment: Seems to be primarily written in Spanish. I'll see if I can understand what the code is doing

Comment: It also won't run the system logging, it says it cannot load a dll

Comment: It's wierd, but if you compile the project into an .exe it works (you may have to copy the dll file into the same directory as the exe).  Include the Callback.vb (edit for your own projects purposes) and Declarations.vb into your own project, compile, and run with that dll in the same directory and it will work.  It will make debugging a chore and its not very flexible, but what do you expect for something free.

Comment: After giving up on the project for a while, I restarted. The suggested solution only works for exactly 618 keystrokes, and then ceases to function. Something about garbagecollecting the delegate function.